# i could not edit data by using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have an issue with update new data by using react-redux, Add and remove are working fine, but it will return null object when i want to edit one of the data.
I am not sure what stage cause wrong.

action.users.js

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
// ADD_USER
export const addUser = ({ username = '', location = '' } = {}) => ({
  type: 'ADD_USER',
  user: { id: uuid(), username, location },
});

//REMOVE_USER
export const removeUser = ({ id } = {}) => ({ type: 'REMOVE_USER', id });

//EDIT_USER
export const editUser = ({ id, updates } = {}) => ({
  type: 'EDIT_USER',
  id,
  updates,
});
```

components.EditUserPage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import UserForm from './UserForm';
import { editUser } from '../actions/users';

const EditUserPage = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <UserForm
        user={props.user}
        onSubmit={user => {
          props.dispatch(editUser(props.user.id, user));
          props.history.push('/Users');
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    user: state.user.find(user => user.id === props.match.params.id),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditUserPage);
```

reducers.users.js

```
const usersReducerDefaultState = [];
export default (state = usersReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_USER':
      return [...state, action.user];
    case 'REMOVE_USER':
      return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
    case 'EDIT_USER':
      return state.map(user => {
        if (user.id === action.id) {
          return {
            ...user,
            ...action.updates,
          };
        } else {
          return user;
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The page should go to ./edit when i click one of the data and the input value will show the currently selected data in the userform component. it seems like going well at this stage, i change the input value and click the create button, the page back to /User, unfortunately, the selected data return null object. please help me. you answer will help me to jump out of this nightmare.

Comment: Have you tested your `UserForm` and ensured it is passing the correct data to `onSubmit`?

Comment: i think so. The input value show selected data in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```js
props.dispatch(editUser(props.user.id, user));
```

to

```js
props.dispatch(editUser({id: props.user.id, updates: user}));
```

You define the method signature of edit user as

```js
function editUser ({ id, updates } = {}) {…}
```

That is, a function that takes one (optional) argument. That argument is expected to be an object with an `id` and `updates` property. (I don't think you should make the argument optional. It is needed for the rest of the function to work.)

However, you call the function with two arguments, presumable a number and an object. Also, if `props.user.id` ends up being `undefined`, then it will be replaced with the default value of `{}`, and id and updates will be `undefined`, but no error will occur (which is what you want, because you are passing the wrong type to the function).

Alternatively, you could define the method signature to take to positional arguments and not change the function call:

```js
const editUser = (id, updates) => (…)
```

or, if your `UserForm` component includes `id` in the call to `onSubmit`:

```js
const editUser = ({ id, ...updates }) => (…) // use destructuring to select the id from the argument

// call it like this:
props.dispatch(editUser({user}));
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work, it returns previous data.

Comment: Then I believe you have two problems. I think this should fix the problem as described in the question.

Comment: yeah, i have changed my code with your suggestion, it should be const editUser = ( id, updates ) => ({
  type: 'EDIT_USER',
  id,
  updates,
});